# jQuery touch and swipe

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, touch, swipe

I am creating jquery slider for mobile device. For touch and swipe I am using [touchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/) plugin.

It's working fine when you swipe on blank area but it's not working when I swipe on anchor links.

here is my html code.

```
<article data-status="loaded" id="deals-most-popular" class="deals-tube deals-populate-region">
  <div class="col-1">
    <ul data-category="most-popular">
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/21486/102/florida-car-rentals-from-tampa-orlando-miami-more"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 15+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Florida</strong> Florida Car Rentals from Tampa, Orlando, Miami &amp; More </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/114021/102/myrtle-beach-hotel-deals-vacation-packages-in-spring-w-extras"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 30+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Myrtle Beach</strong> Myrtle Beach Hotel Deals &amp; Vacation Packages in Spring w/Extras </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/103392/102/fly-round-trip-to-cities-worldwide-on-emirates"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 634+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>South America</strong> Fly Round-Trip to Cities Worldwide on Emirates </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37068/102/rome-florence-venice-7-nts-w-air-train-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1665+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Italy</strong> Rome, Florence &amp; Venice: 7 Nts w/Air, Train &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37045/102/athens-istanbul-6-nights-w-flights-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1159+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>World</strong> Athens &amp; Istanbul: 6 Nights w/Flights &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <ul data-category="most-popular">
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37053/102/london-paris-rome-9-nts-w-air-transfer-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1859+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Europe</strong> London, Paris &amp; Rome: 9 Nts w/Air, Transfer &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37063/102/prague-vienna-budapest-7-nts-w-air-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1445+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Europe</strong> Prague, Vienna &amp; Budapest: 7 Nts w/Air &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37060/102/barcelona-rome-6-nts-w-air-transfer-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1429+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Europe</strong> Barcelona &amp; Rome: 6 Nts w/Air, Transfer &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/108188/102/6-nights-at-the-bahamas-paradise-island-all-incl-resort-w-air"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 859+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Bahamas</strong> 6 Nights at the Bahamas Paradise Island All-Incl. Resort w/Air </span> </a> </li>
      <li itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope=""> <a target="_blank" itemprop="url" href="http://staging.click.deals.shermanstravel.com/37064/102/barcelona-ibiza-6-nt-package-w-air-hotel"> <span class="deal-price" itemprop="price"> <em> <sup>$</sup> 1245+ </em> </span> <span class="deal-text" itemprop="name"> <strong>Spain</strong> Barcelona &amp; Ibiza 6-Nt Package w/Air &amp; Hotel </span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

**Script**

```
![$(function() {      
      //Enable swiping...
      $("#deals-most-popular").swipe( {
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
          if(direction === "left"){
              $(this).cycle("next");
             // alert('left')
          } else if(direction === "right"){
              $(this).cycle("prev");
              //alert('right')
          }
        },
        //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
         threshold:0
      });
    });][3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anchors ("a") elements are excluded from swiping by default (see the "excludedElements" property).

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/docs/symbols/%24.fn.swipe.defaults.html

You can make links swipe by setting that list to be more appropriate for your needs, but then you might need to deal with the anchors not executing their native "link" action (android only?) (probably using the "tap" (previously called "click") handler).

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Tap_vs_swipe.html

HTH,

Andy